# Android: Cannot stop text from moving

Tags: android

I am trying to display the accelerometer data in 3 rows like this:

X: 9.8 m/s2
Y: 0.0 m/s2
Z: -3.2 m/s2

But no matter what I have tried, I cannot seem to prevent the m/s2 from shifting back and forth when one of the values goes above 9.9 or negative.

E.g.

Before
X: 0.0 m/s2

After
X: -5.0 m/s2

I have tried tablelayout but the column just stretches, relativelayout, linearlayout and every possible padding combination I can think of.

Here's a sample of my XML code which is inside of a vertical linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout           
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X:"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30sp"
        android:paddingRight="30sp"
        android:text="        "
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/xAccelUnits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="           "
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fix the size of the text view. It can be either a width in dp : layout_width="30dp"

or you can use weights: layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1" for each TextView so that each takes a third of the screen (by modifying the weight and the weight_sum in the linear layout, you can give the width in fractions of the screen width)

Comment: Fantastic, the 'layout_width' did the trick. I had already tried the weights but they were too frustrating to get correct and continued to shift (perhaps something else was wrong). I am grateful for your time!

Comment: no problem. as for the weight, it needs a fixed width to work as you would like, since the /remaining/ space is distributed (0 or more dp)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem myself, this is how I solved it, with a slight adaptation for your case:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#00.00000"); //put this somewhere where you don't have to recreate it every time you get a new value.
String xAcc = df.format(event.values[0]);
xValueView.setText(xAcc);
```

(Where xValueView is the TextView in which you want to display the value)

Comment: Thank you, but that wouldn't solve the case with the negative number. I used the Math.round function to accomplish a similar result.

Comment: Actually it does. The # makes sure that there is always either a -sign or an empty space. I prefer this method, as you get the decimals in the same spots all the time.

Comment: that makes sense. but you need to use a monospace font, don't you?

Comment: At least you'll need a font where all numbers are of equal width (which all the standard droid-fonts are)

Comment: @Jave my apologies, thank you for your answer and explanation.

Comment: No need to apologize. Hopefully it will come in handy for someone in the future :)